How to allow to select only 1.5 hour duration in fullcalendar
Fullcalender has 15 minute slots:
javascript:
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
const calOpts = {
  locale: 'ee',
  slotDuration: '00:15:00',
  slotLabelInterval: '00:15',
  allDaySlot: false,
  selectConstraint: 'businessHours',
  select : function( selectionInfo  ) {
     document.getElementById('start').value = selectionInfo.start
     },
    selectable: true,
   events: { url: 'api/fullcalendar' }
   }
  const calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar')
  calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, calOpts)
  calendar.render()
  })

html:
<form action="~/kinnitatud" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="start" id="start" />
<input type='submit'/>
</form>

Selectable event duration is 1.5 hours and it occurs in same day. Using this code user can select start time so that there in less than 1.5 hours to next event or to end of day.
Also it can select event by dragging it to be more or less than 1.5 hours.
How to disable such selection so that user can select only 1.5 hour event in free time area?
Fullcalendar 7 beta version is used in ASP.NET 9 MVC view.
